# ES6 - generators using for count

Tags: ecmascript-6

I was trying to create a counter using generators where user will click on the button and the count value will be increased. When i tried to get the function i am not getting that one. Am i missing something .

Thanks in Advance

index.html

```
  <div class="counter">
     <div id="count-gen">0</div>
     <button onclick="countGen()">Count</button>
    </div>
```

index.js

```
 function* countGen(){
    let count =0;
    let nextValue = yield count++
    document.getElementById('count-gen').innerHTML = nextValue
  }
```

Comment: You keep calling the generator function, instead of calling it once and then invoking `next` on the returned generator.

Comment: i didn't understood it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've conflated two things which should be separate: Your generator, and the event handler for *using* your generator. You also need to be using the generator's iterator:

The *generator* (note the loop):

```
function* countGen() {
  let count = 0;
  while (true) {
    yield ++count;
  }
}
```

*(I also made it a pre-increment as you appeared to want to start at 1.)*

Getting the iterator:

```
const count = countGen();
```

Using the iterator:

```
function handler() {
  document.getElementById('count-gen').innerHTML = count.next().value;
}
```

Live Example:

```js
function* countGen() {
  let count = 0;
  while (true) {
    yield ++count;
  }
}

const count = countGen();

function handler() {
  document.getElementById('count-gen').innerHTML = count.next().value;
}

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", handler);
```

```html
<div class="counter">
  <div id="count-gen">0</div>
  <button>Count</button>
</div>
```

*(The example also uses `addEventListener` rathern than an `onxyz`-attribute handler.)*